# how to mark mail as read in lotus mail (using NCSO jar)?

Tags: lotus-notes

I am developing a email client for lotus Notes using NCSO jar but while saving the mail as draft its coming as unread mail . Is there any property I can use to set it read ? I have  tried markRead() but its says NOT implemented.

Comment: How do you save the document? `NotesDocument.save` has the parameter `MarkAsRead`...

Comment: I used document.save() to save the notes document, it does have method called markRead() but when I use it. It says ::NotesException: Not implemented
 at lotus.domino.cso.Base.notImplemented(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.cso.Document.markRead(Unknown Source)

Comment: Does `document.save(false,false,true)` work?

Comment: gr8 man this works... but could you please explain these booleans used?

Comment: I've added an answer with the details about the flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark a [NotesDocument](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS.html) as read when saving, call [save](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS.html) with the third boolean option (Mark read) set to true. In your case, `document.save(false,false,true)` will work.

Here is a quote from the above urls with emphasis on this flag:

> **Syntax**
>
> `flag = notesDocument.Save( force, createResponse [, markRead ] )`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `force`
>
> Boolean. If True, the document is saved even if someone else edits and
>   saves the document while the script is running. The last version of
>   the document that was saved wins; the earlier version is discarded.
>
> If False, and someone else edits the document while the script is
>   running, the createResponse argument determines what happens.
>
> `createResponse`
>
> Boolean. If True, the current document becomes a response to the
>   original document (this is what the replicator does when there's a
>   replication conflict). If False, the save is canceled. If the force
>   parameter is True, the createResponse parameter has no effect.
>
> `markRead`
>
> Boolean. *If **True**, the document is marked as read on behalf of the
>   current user ID. If **False (default)**, the document is not marked as
>   read.*